# How can I check what sentence it's on in this code in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I followed a tutorial and I created a nice dialogue system. The thing is, I would like my character to do an animation when it stops talking. Is there a way to check what sentence my character is on to do that?

Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;
public class DialogueController : MonoBehaviour
{

    public TextMeshProUGUI DialogueText;
    public string[] Sentences;
    private int Index = 0;
    public float DialogueSpeed;
    bool collide = false;
    private bool nextText = true;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (collide == true)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
            {   if (nextText == true)
                {
                    nextText = false;
                    NextSentence();

                }
                
            }
        }
    }
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        collide = true;
        
    }

    void NextSentence()
    {
        if (Index <= Sentences.Length - 1)
        {
            DialogueText.text = "";
            StartCoroutine(WriteSentence());
        }
    }

    IEnumerator WriteSentence()
    {
        foreach(char Character in Sentences[Index].ToCharArray()) 
        {
            DialogueText.text += Character;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(DialogueSpeed);
        }
        Index++;
        nextText = true;
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Well you appear to have a variable called index which is showing what sentence youre on.

Comment: It worked! If you put this comment as an answer, I will mark it as solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TBH I feel a bit guilty writing this up as an answer because really there was no answer, it was already there.. However

The variable index in the class shows what sentence you're on.

Comment: Nah it totally helped.